# Как импортировать и использовать JS файл в компоненте Vue

Tags: vue.js

Как импортировать JS файл и использовать его методы?

chatkit.js:

```
function test() {
    window.console.log("TEST CHAT SUCES:");
}
export {test}
```

Component.vue

```
<script>
    import {test} from 'chatkit.js'
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            loading: true,
            teamLoading: true,
            team: [],
            chat: {},
            messages: [],
            dialog: {
                status: false,
                message: ''
            }
        }),
        methods: {

            testium: function () {
                test();
            }
        },
        mounted() {

        }
    }
</script>
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'chatkit.js'

js файл и компонент находятся в одной директории:

C:\Users\User\vue_project\src\views\my\pages\chat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй так

```
export function test() {
    window.console.log("TEST CHAT SUCES:");
}
```

А в компоненте

```
<script>
    import {test} from './chatkit.js'

    // тут всё остальное
</script>
```